# Display First/Last Post from each Categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm new for `WordPress`. I need to display First/Last Post from Each Parent Categories. That may be in any sub-category.

I need Simple code to get that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$category = get_categories();
foreach ($category as $cat)
{
    query_posts( array ( 'cat' => $cat->cat_ID, 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
    echo '<div class="post">';
    echo '<h2>'.$cat->cat_name.'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    while (have_posts())
    {
        the_post();
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    $category_id = get_cat_ID($cat->cat_name);
    $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);
    echo '<div class="paging">';
    echo '<a href="'.$category_link.'" title="'.$cat->cat_name.'">More Post from '.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: 'posts_per_page' => 5 indicate to show the first 5 of latest post

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using a custom query here is the query I executed:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT a.*, d.name as category FROM wp_posts AS a
     INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS b ON b.object_id = a.ID
     INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS c ON b.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_taxonomy_id AND c.parent = 0
     INNER JOIN wp_terms AS d ON d.term_id = c.term_id AND c.taxonomy = 'category'
     ORDER BY a.post_date DESC
  ) as f
GROUP BY f.category
ORDER BY f.post_date DESC;
```

What this does is get full dataset of posts that are related to category taxonomy then will sorted it in descending mode so It will have the lastest post in first place then group it by category and once again sort it back. If you want to get the oldest just change DESC to ASC.

I use this script in a database will 127,000 posts and even though my server is quite strong It takes 0.0042seg to execute this query.

Hope this might help someone, cheers!